# Aspnet5 - ServiceStack.Redis - custom session provider

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, servicestack.redis

In earlier versions of .Net, custom session state provider was specified in web.config as

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="ServiceStackRedisSessionStateProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="RedisSessionStateProvider" type="clsServiceStackRedisSessionStateStoreProvider"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
</system.web>
```

Using VS 2015, Aspnet5 RC1 - update1, to add session in the project -> Startup.cs -> Configure method  the following code is used

```
 app.UseSession();
```

By default, a new AspNet5, web application project uses some in built session provider.
1. How to specify custom session state provider
2. How to add ServiceStack.Redis as custom session state provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your ConfigureServices

```
services.AddSingleton<IDistributedCache, RedisCache>(); //this replaces the default in memory cache with Rdis
services.Configure<RedisCacheOptions>(redisOptions =>
            {
                redisOptions.Configuration = Configuration["Redis:Configuration"]; //ie - localhost
                redisOptions.InstanceName = Configuration["Redis:InstanceName"];
            });
services.AddCaching();
```

in Configure

```
app.UseSession();
```

also you will need these dependencies

"Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis": "1.0.0-rc1-final",

and this only works with the full framework, not .net core

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at samples provided by Asp.Net Team https://github.com/aspnet/Session/tree/dev/samples/SessionSample

Answer (score 0):

ServiceStack.Redis [is not supported yet](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/issues/121) (current status - [alpha2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis/1.1.0-alpha2)). I suggest you to take a look at [Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis) which is probably bit more production-ready.